# Auxiliary GCD Functional beginner

Tags: f#

So I have this

```
// Greatest common divisor

    let rec gcd x y =
      if y = 0 then x
       else gcd y (x%y)

//multiplying fraction using tuples. So , instead of /

    let (.*)(a,b)(c,d)=((a*c)/(gcd (a*c) (b*d)),((d*b)/(gcd(a*c)(d*b))));;

//adding fractions using tuples and simplifying

    let (.+)(a,b)(c,d)=((a*d+c*b)/(gcd(a*d+c*b)(d*b)),(d*b)/(gcd(a*d+c*b)(d*b)));;
```

It works flawlessly, but i want to be able to do this using Auxiliary functions.

I have

`let rec gcd = function
  | (a,0) -> a
  | (a,b) -> gcd (b, a % b)`

,but i am unfamiliar with how to get it to work. Every time i try to implement it, it doesn't call the gcd. I'm sure its a f# syntac thing. Namely because I am new to the language and haven't seen enough examples. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post all of your code? As it is `(.*)` and `(.+)` expect a curried `gcd` so it would not work with your tuple-`gcd` - so I guess you just added yours *after* the other code and as F# works top to bottom it will happily use the first one

Comment: let (.*)(a,b)(c,d)=
   let rec gcd = function
     | (a,0) -> a
     | (a,b) -> gcd (b, a % b)
   ((a*c)/(gcd ((a*c), (b*d))),((d*b)/(gcd((a*c),(d*b)))));;

Comment: Thanks Carsten. It was a spacing issue. Glad I looked it over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let rec gcd a b = 
    match a, b with
    | (a,0) -> a
    | (a,b) -> gcd b (a % b)
```